# 5 values for a face in PLY files?

Tags: ply

I was just barely introduced to .ply files and I don't understand how they work. The vertex list has only 3 values for each vertex: x,y,z. But each face has 5 values and I don't know what those 5 values mean. I just need a little explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This simply means that the face has 5 sides or 5 vertices and each vertex's position is specified in space by the 3 values x,y,z.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is not exactly right to my knowledge.
The first value is the number of vertices  which define the face, in your case it should be 4, as there are only 4 numbers left. The four other numbers are indices of the vertices. Like often in computer science, the index of the first vertex is 0, not 1.

Some programs though support only triangular meshes, and faces with more than 3 edges are not supported.

Furthermore, if you use a visualization program which adds light and other rendering stuff, the face 3 0 1 2 is not the same as 3 0 2 1 as the triangle has another orientation.